# Specifying input.json file from another directory for use in opa test

Tags: json, opa, rego

I am new to opa/rego and have an opa test that I would like to run. Within that test .rego file, I would like to use an input.json file from a different directory. Is there a way to specify that file within a "with input as _____" statement within the test file? i.e.

```
test_allow {
    allow with input as <path-to-file>
}
```

My thoughts so far have lead me to trying the -b option but the directories are pretty far apart and I do not want a bundle that large and dependent. Additionally, I have thought about the import statements but I do not have the "-i" option within the opa test subcommand. I've also tried specifying each file (the .rego policy file, the .rego test file, and an input file) within the opa test subcommand to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

OPA, and by extension the OPA test runner, doesn't really consider *files* at the time of policy evaluation. When OPA starts, all the files/directories pointed out by the command are merged under the `data` attribute, and may then be referenced byt their path, e.g. `data.my-mocks.mock1`, and so on.

If you want to include "test data" in your tests, you could keep those files in a directory included when running the `opa test` command. Since all data files are merged though, you'll need to ensure there aren't conflicting paths in those files. This is commonly accomplished by using a unique "top level" attribute per item. Something like:

```json
{
    "mock1": {
        "item": "here"
    },
    "mock2": {
        "item": "here"
    }
}
```

You may then reference this in your tests like you suggested:

```
test_allow {
    allow with input as data.mock1.item
}
```

Comment: In hindsight, I was looking to "test" my policies against the actual Cloud Formation Templates outputted by my AWSCDK pipeline. Therefore, I probably meant to use regular 'opa eval' to evaluate my policies within my pipeline. 

However, this info certainly helps. I will likely look to include a couple test input files within my testing directory. Thank you!

Comment: I see! Sounds like conftest could be of interest to you: https://www.conftest.dev/